# php force download script no longer works

Tags: php

We have been using the following script to download photos but now it no longer works. At the `is_file` function it redirects like it should if its not a file to the actual image location, which the image is there. If I take that out, it downloads but the jpg has an error. Not sure becuase the image is there (you get redirected to it if it wont downloads).

```
<?php

  ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

  $sourceFile = $_GET['file'];

  $sourceFile = urldecode($sourceFile);


  if( headers_sent() )
    die('Headers Sent');

  if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

  if (!is_file( $sourceFile ))
    header( 'Location:'. $sourceFile ) ;

  $len = filesize($sourceFile);
  $filename = basename($sourceFile);
  $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));

  switch( $file_extension ) {
    case "pdf"  : $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
    case "exe"  : $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
    case "zip"  : $ctype="application/zip"; break;
    case "doc"  : $ctype="application/msword"; break;
    case "xls"  : $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
    case "ppt"  : $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
    case ".docx": $ctype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"; break;
    case ".pptx": $ctype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"; break;
    case ".xlsx": $ctype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"; break;
    case "gif"  : $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png"  : $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg" :
    case "jpg"  : $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
    case "mp3"  : $ctype="audio/mpeg"; break;
    case "wav"  : $ctype="audio/x-wav"; break;
    case "mpeg" :
    case "mpg"  :
    case "mpe"  : $ctype="video/mpeg"; break;
    case "mov"  : $ctype="video/quicktime"; break;
    case "avi"  : $ctype="video/x-msvideo"; break;
    case "mp4"  : $ctype="video/mpeg"; break;

    //The following are for extensions that shouldn't be downloaded
    case "php"  :
    case "css"  :
    case "js"   :
    case "htm"  :
    case "html" :
    case "txt"  : die("<b>Cannot be used for ". $file_extension ." files!</b>"); break;

    default     : $ctype="application/force-download";
  }

  header("Pragma: public");
  header("Expires: 0");
  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header("Cache-Control: public");
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
  header("Content-Type: $ctype");
  $header="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.";";
  header($header );
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  header("Content-Length: ".$len);
  echo file_get_contents($sourceFile);
  exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that might cause `is_file()` to fail:

1. What about your environment changed between when it worked and when it stopped working? Make sure you check the file permissions, including the parent directory.
2. Does it work with certain images and not others? Might be that your file size is larger than your integer storage. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php):

   > **Note:** Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB.
3. Does the filename contain any foreign characters? Try removing them.
4. Have you tried using the full absolute path `/var/www/html/images/file.jpg` instead of the relative path `/images/file.jpg`?
5. Have you tried an alternative function such as [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)?

Onto your second problem, the `.jpg` produces an error even without the file check.

1. What is the error exactly, or do you mean it downloads corrupted file?

I copy & pasted your code onto my local test environment and it appears to work correctly without any errors. If the information above doesn't help, please update your question with more details.

Comment: 1.) Wordpress what I am working on and no file permissions changed 2.)Doesnt work on any any more and the files size is like 1.1 MB. 3.)No foreign characters and use urldecode() 4.)the path I use is similar to http://example.com/wp-content/02/theimage.jpg                    As for the jpeg it says "The file “Ec_4K5A0220.jpg” could not be opened because it is empty."

Comment: @Packy can you provide one of the images? Like I said, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code. So it's either something with the server config, or the image itself.

Comment: Ya thats what I was thinking. The image I can download just fine the old fashion way of going to the link and right hand click download.

Comment: So nothing on the server changed, images are fine, code just mysteriously stopped working (but works for me)... Something doesn't add up. Gotta help me in order to let me help you.

Comment: I understand that. I will just close the question. This is taking over someone elses project so the server could have changed. I just wasnt sure if there was something I wasnt seeing code wise